# Eclipse ALT shortcut of Windows on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I am used on programming with Eclipse using the Windows and Linux platform. I could easily adopt with the shortcuts because of the keyboard. It so happened that I have to adopt to Macintosh for work.

As Eclipse programmers, the `Alt` key on Windows and Linux is a big help in many ways. When creating a new class, just hold the 'Alt' key then the new combination(s) will be underlined by Eclipse to perform which button/field you wanna process (`Alt`+ V - add/skip `public static void main(String[] args)` on the new class). I don't know the counter part of that shortcut to Macintosh.

Does anyone knows the shortcut/binding to it?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this functionality does not exist in OS X.
However, you may find it useful to access the menus (outside the create new... dialog) using ctrl + F2 (or ctrl + fn + F2 if the function buttons are used for volume etc).
Eg. to access File > Open File ... you could do:

> ctrl + F2, F, arrow down, O, enter

This is not as quick as in Windows, but it can be a workaround.

Comment: Doesn't exist in OS X or in Eclipse? I've been using Macs for a fair few years now and it still iritates me that there's no convenient way to jump to specific menus/buttons. I'd hate to think there's an #ifdef somewhere that's switching off the Alt-key bindings when I'd love to use it so much. I recently tested out Linux Mint and gave Eclipse a quick spin on it and things like the New Project wizards are so much more usable as a result of the Alt-key bindings!